# How to clear the previous value entered in text field and pass new value to same field in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

i have written selenium script to read value from excel and pass it to text field. I am facing below mentioned issue

First i have passed invalid values to text field through sendkeys(). in second time, i am sending correct values to field through sendkeys(). But it is appending to the previous value.

How I can clear previously entered value in text field and pass new value to same fields

Can anyone provide solution for this

Answer (score 1):

```
element.clear
element.sendkeys(value)
```

if you want to make this a one line step which combines clear and sendkeys, then you have many options, some dependent on the language you are using.

eg.

- create a helper method which takes element and value
- extend Element class and create a new method called Setvalue
- Overwrite the existing sendkeys with a new method which calls clear first

Each of these have pros and cons and may be dependent on the language you use

Comment: i am using java, now i am using code as driver.findElement(By.id("xxx")).sendKeys("abc");                              how i can use above set of code for this code

Comment: Find the element, store in a variable. Call clear, then call sendKeys

Comment: So your question has been answered?

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the job in Java. Put it before you enter the second piece of text.

```
_driver.findElement(By.id/css/xpath("element")).clear();
```